# grunt create and run less compile task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

i am very new to grunt and i wanted to achieve following goal

- iterate every directory in pointed location
- compile less file to css

source:

- theme 1

  - file.less
- theme 2

  - file.less
- theme 3

  - file.less

after processing:

- theme 1

  - file.less
  - out.css
- theme 2

  - file.less
  - out.css
- theme 3

  - file.less
  - out.css

I read somewhere that grunt does that, this is my entire run.js file:

```
var grunt = require('grunt'),
    less = require('less');

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      compileCore: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ['themes/**/file.less'], 
          ext: '.css',
          extDot: 'first'
        }]
      }
  }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);

  grunt.task.run('default');
```

it doesnt give any errors but it doesnt work either, how can i make this to work? (again, i have no exprience with grunt whatsoever, yet)

if its possible also to achieve this goal with just command line execution (without runing node.js file) that would be good too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use grunt.file.expandMapping (https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expandmapping)
 to iterate through all the files in a directory and provide options to according to the requirements.

The below code will work according to your requirement.

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['themes/**/*.less'], '', {
                    rename: function (destBase, destPath) {
                        return destBase + destPath.replace('.less', '.css');
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
}
```